# Energy of discretization Schrodinger equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We are well known that the continuous Schrodinger system:

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    u_t + iu_{xx} = 0  \qquad                        & x \in [0, 1]\\
    u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0 \qquad        & T \geq t \ge 0\\
    u(x,0) = u_0              \qquad                       & x \in [0,1]\\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}
where $u_0 \in H_0^1(0,1)$ has the conserved energy:

$E(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}|u_x(x,t)|^2\,dx$

i.e: $E(t)=E(0)$. Now we consider the discretization of Schrodinger system. Let $h = \tfrac{1}{N+1}$ where $N$ is a nonnegative integer. Consider the subdivision $x_j = jh$ for $j = 0,...,N+1$ and the system:

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    u_j'(t) + i\frac{u_{j+1}(t)-2u_j(t)+u_{j-1}(t)}{h^2} = 0 \qquad                        & t \in (0,T), j = 1,...,N\\
    u_0(t) = u_{N+1}(t) = 0 \qquad        & t \in (0,T)\\
    u_j(0) = u_j^0              \qquad   & j = 1,...,N\\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}
The energy is given by

$E_h(t) = \frac{h}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{N}\Bigl|\tfrac{u_{j+1}(t)-u_j(t)}{h}\Bigr|^2$

How can we prove $E_h(t) = E_h(0)$ for all $t$ ?

Comment: Express $E'(t)$ in term of differences of $u_j(t)$ and see what you get

Comment: I did it, but I see no results. Can you write explicitly ?

Comment: Maybe $E'(t) \ne 0$ so the claim is not true, but for sure you can replace $u_j'(t)$ by $i\frac{...}{h}$ to express $E'(t_0)$ as a sum over $u_.(t_0)$. In the continuous case you need to integrate by parts to show $E'(t) = 0$. In the discrete case, try using [partial summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), and show us what you get.